# How to stop refreshing fragment on tab change with FragmentStateAdapter and ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using FragementStateAdapter and ViewPager2 in my Android project. But the problem is that my fragment is being reloaded on tab change. I want to stop that how do I do that? I have tried many online methods like specifying the setOffScreenLimit etc but nothing didn't work for me. Here is my code

Here is my adapter code

```
public class LandingAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public LandingAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return mFragmentList.get(position).hashCode();
    }

}
```

Here is my Activity code

```
        ViewPager2 mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
        TabLayout mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.TabLayout);



        LandingAdapter mAdapter = new LandingAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        int savedAppMode = SharedPrefs.getInt(this, "app_mode_checked_item",0);
        if (savedAppMode == 1) {
            mAdapter.addFragment(new ItemsFrag1());
            mAdapter.addFragment(new ContactsFrag1());
            mAdapter.addFragment(new ImagesFrag1());
        } else {
            mAdapter.addFragment(new ItemsFrag2());
            mAdapter.addFragment(new ContactsFrag2());
            mAdapter.addFragment(new ImagesFrag2());
        }


        new TabLayoutMediator(mTabLayout, mViewPager, (tab, position) -> {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tab.setText("Items");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.x_icon_photo);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tab.setText("Contacts");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.x_icon_video);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tab.setText("Images");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.x_icon_download);
                    break;
            }
        }).attach();
```

Comment: `setOffScreenPageLimit(2)` would usually work fine in this case. You sure you are using it?

Comment: @Darshan Yes its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setRetainInstance(true) inside onCreate() of your fragments with FragmentPagerAdapter.

Or

You can use limit for it

```
 int limit = (adapter.getCount() > 1 ? adapter.getCount() - 1 : 1);
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
```